# ANTLR rule precedence with implicit tokens

Tags: antlr

I am using ANTLR and have stumbled upon something that is confusing me:

```
grammar Test;

testA: 'a' 'b' 'c' | 'ab';
testB: 'abc' | 'ab';
```

Given the input of "abc" on `testA` it is parsing "ab" (right side) but on `testB` it is parsing "abc" (left side). From researching the lexer, I was under the impression that it would always try to find the longest match.

I would have expected it to output "a" "b" "c" in the first case and "abc" in the second case (left side both times) as these are both listed first, and longer.

```
function
    : 'afunc' '(' 'args'? ')' // line 1:5 mismatched input '()' expecting '('
    | 'bfunc' '()'
    ;
```

Similarly, the input of "afunc()" fails in this example and it tokenizes to `()` over the `(` and `)`. What explains these behaviors, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The parser behaved correctly in both situations. For `testA` the longest single match is `ab`. The 3 single letter tokens are that, each a single token.

For `testB` the string `abc` is longer than `ab`, so it matches in this case.

With this information it should be clear what to do: combine lexer tokens into one if you want to match them as one.

Answer (score 0):

> Given the input of "abc" on testA it is parsing "ab" (right side)

It may look like it's parsing correctly (because the parser might try to recover and continue parsing), but it really isn't. For the input `"abc"`, the token `'ab'` will not be created.

Given the grammar:

```
grammar Test;

testA: 'a' 'b' 'c' | 'ab';
testB: 'abc' | 'ab';
```

and the code:

```java
TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(CharStreams.fromString("abc"));
TestParser parser = new TestParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
parser.testA();
```

the parser will produce an error:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'abc' expecting {'a', 'ab'}
```

Because `"abc"` will **always** be tokenized as a single token. It does not matter what parser rule you're trying to match. The lexer operates independently from the parser.

> I would have expected it to output "a" "b" "c" in the first case and "abc"

No, see my previous remark about the lexer working independently from the parser.

> Similarly, the input of "afunc()" fails in this example and it tokenizes to () over the ( and ). What explains these behaviors, what is the solution?

I don't know what you mean by "solution", because I don;t see a problem. This is just how the lexer works:

1. it tries to match as much characters as possible when creating tokens
2. when 2 or more lexer rules can match the same characters, the one defined first "wins"

Given these 2 rules, it is clear (or should be) that the input `"afunc()"` creates only 2 tokens:

- `afunc`
- `()` (not a `(` and `)` token because of the first rule: match as much characters as possible)

In this case, you shouldn't create a token like `()`, it should be 2 separate tokens `(` and `)`:

```
function
    : 'afunc' '(' 'args'? ')'
    | 'bfunc' '(' ')'
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to understand that when you put literal strings into a parser rule, ANTLR will create token rules for you (it’ll just make up names for those tokens (so I usually prefer to (mostly) avoid literals like this).

Logically, this is treated in ANTLR as though you had this grammar:

```
grammar Test;

TOK_1 : ‘a’;
TOK_2 : ‘b’;
TOK_3 : ‘c’;
TOK_4 : ‘ab’;
TOK_5 : ‘abc’;

testA: TOK_1 TOK_2 TOK_3 | TOK_4;
testB: TOK_5 | TOK_4
;
```

When you undertand that ANTLR first analyses your input stream of characters to produce a steam of tokens (and that the Lexer will always select the longer Token rule that matches you input).

As a result, your input of ‘abc’ will always be tokenized as a stream of one  TOK_5 token, and testB is the parser rule that deals with that token.

(It’s easy, when placing literals in parser rules, to think of them as something that is evaluated as part of running the parser rule.  It’s really just a convenience (and generally just used for tokens you won’t really need to care about in your parseTree)